# Gradle: Trying to figure out an EOF error. Userguide: Example 14.5. Configuring arbitrary objects using a script.

Tags: gradle, eof

I am on page 78 of the gradle userguide: Example 14.5. Configuring arbitrary objects using a script.

I have copied all of the code in the example:

build.gradle

```
task configure << { 
    pos = java.text.FieldPosition( ) new 10 
    // Apply the script 
    apply from: 'other.gradle', to: pos 
    println pos.beginIndex 
    println pos.endIndex 
}
```

other.gradle

```
beginIndex = 1; 
endIndex = 5;
```

Output of gradle -q configure

```
D:\Gradle\ThisAndThat>gradle -q configure

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: Build file 'D:\Gradle\ThisAndThat\build.gradle' line: 1

What went wrong: Could not compile build file 'D:\Gradle\ThisAndThat\build.gradle'. 
> startup failed: 
    build file 'D:\Gradle\ThisAndThat\build.gradle': 1: expecting EOF, found 'configure' @ line 1, column 6. 
    task configure << { ^ 
1 error
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I literally copy the code from [Chapter 14.5 of the userguide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#N10C67) it works. Your mistake is in the build.gradle script:

```
task configure << { 
    pos = java.text.FieldPosition( ) new 10
```

should be

```
task configure << { 
    pos = new java.text.FieldPosition(10)
```